Cannot enable pstore by yocto in linux
I already add pstore related kernel configs and add pstore_blk.blkdev=xxx in /proc/cmdline
But /sys/fs/pstore always empty and I have no permission to access.(root fs is read-only)


dmesg just have one:

I have no idea about it. Hoping somebody can help me.

My rootfs is readonly:
root@corbos-linux:~# mount -o remount,rw / mount: /: cannot remount /dev/mapper/rootfs read-write, is write-protected.
